# SSLCertVerification Error when connecting to OECD

Tags: python, api, limit

Here is my function. It was working yesterday, but not any more.

```
from cif import cif 

def make_oecd_request():
    country = ['AUS','AUT']
    dsname = 'B1_GE'
    measure = ['GPSA']
    frequency = 'Q'
    startDate = '1947-Q1'
    endDate = '2021-Q3'
    
    data, subjects, measures = cif.createDataFrameFromOECD(countries=countries,
dsname=dsname,measure=measure,
frequency=frequency,startDate=startDate,endDate=endDate)
```

Here is the error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stats.oecd.org', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: 
/SDMX-JSON/data/B1_GE/AUS..GPSA.Q/all?startTime=1947-Q1&endTime=2021-Q3
&dimensionAtObservation
=AllDimensions (Caused by 
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] 
certificate verify failed: 
unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: [Terms of use](https://www.oecd.org/termsandconditions/) is a good place to start, generally

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how you believe an SSL verification error has anything to do with an API limit?

Comment: The error message does say "Max retries exceed with url", hence my assumption, however, the error message could be misleading therefore I'm open to the idea that something else could be the root cause

Comment: Thank you for the advice @SilvioMayolo, will check it out

Comment: The Terms of Use state no hard limits, but there is a comment about OECD having the discretion to "to modify the amount of Data You may request in a single query". Have sent them an email as I certainly haven't been pounding their server too much in my opinion. Will wait to hear back from them

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with API limits in this case. Usually when you hit a limit you will get a more explicit message. This is purely an SSL certificate issue. It could have expired or you could have an issue with the intermediary certificate.

First thing you could do is try to hit the endpoint with a browser and look at the certificate (it's typically a padlock icon in the address bar depending on your browser).

If the certificate looks fine, try `pip install --upgrade certifi`

Still doesn't work? You need to get out the big guns. Note that it would be much better if you do this in a virtualized environment.

First step, go to https://www.digicert.com/help/ and search for stats.oecd.org. Note that it will tell you that the server is misconfigured and is not providing the intermediary certificate. Note the name of the certificate in question: `DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1`

Now go to https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm and search for `DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1`. When you find it, download the pem file. Open the file in your favorite editor and copy everything.

Now modify your code like so:

```
import certifi
from cif import cif




def make_oecd_request():
    countries = ["AUS", "AUT"]
    dsname = "B1_GE"
    measure = ["GPSA"]
    frequency = "Q"
    startDate = "1947-Q1"
    endDate = "2021-Q3"

    data, subjects, measures = cif.createDataFrameFromOECD(
        countries=countries,
        dsname=dsname,
        measure=measure,
        frequency=frequency,
        startDate=startDate,
        endDate=endDate,
    )

print(certifi.where())
make_oecd_request()
```

It will still fail, but now it will tell you where the certifi certificate was installed. Open that file and paste the certificate you previously copied at the top. Make sure you include all of it.

You'll find the certificate error is resolved. However, the request is now returning a `400` which means there is an issue with the parameters provided.

Comment: Agreed, it does look like the certificate, not API limits. Hitting the endpoint URL in the browser  shows that the certificate on the site hasn't expired since it shows the padlock. I tried pip install --upgrade certifi and it gave a "Requirement already satisfied" message. But I'm still getting the error. I'm on MacOS Monterey, with Python3.10 btw. Thanks for your guidance it at least guides me in the right direction.

Comment: I updated my comment with the bits needed to get you a bit further.